# How do I recursively use make with sub receipes?

Tags: makefile

I have to Make files like follows:

```
Makefile
foo/
    Makefile
```

Top Make looks like:

```
make-sample:
  cd foo && make all
```

Bottom Make looks like:

```
all:
    ./builder.sh
```

The sub make works as designed and prints out some stuff to the terminal.  When running it from the top make file: `make foo` it doesn't return the same cli output and it makes me think something is not correct.  I was looking at recursion man pages for make https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Recursion.html#Recursion and I was understanding it somewhat.  It looks like i am close, though i don't understand the use of `$(MAKE)` without giving a recipe.

it looks like it wants me to say something like:

```
make-sample:
    cd foo && $(MAKE)
# or
make-sample2:
    $(MAKE) -C foo
```

Can someone better explain to me how to run a sub make with a recipe such that it properly logs the same info to stdout?

Comment: Either of those options will work (the second one requires GNU make).  If you explained exactly what you mean by "doesn't return the same cli output" we might be able to provide some clarity; as it is there's not much we can say.

Comment: When running the sub make, it will echo data to the screen, so i was under the impression that would do the same with the parent wrapper.  Instead it will run with nothing printed/echo'd and then on subsequent runs state that it had no changes.

Comment: Given the makefiles as you show them, the output will be the same regardless of whether you run the sub-make directly or by invoking a parent make that runs the sub-make.  If you are seeing that the output of the sub-directory make is somehow discarded when you run via a parent makefile there must be something else about your environment or setup which is happening, that you haven't shown us here.

Answer (score 1):

On your top directory, `foo` is a directory and you need to explicitly tell `make` that your target name `foo` is not a file, nor a directory by adding this line:

```
.PHONY: foo
```

Otherwise, `make` might do nothing when you do `make foo` from the top directory.

Comment: Can you give more insight as to this answer, such as documentation.  I can change the variables around slightly as well since the folder name really doesnt have a 1:1 map of directory to recipe name

Comment: @Fallenreaper Maybe try [Phony-Targets](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Phony-Targets.html), basically if `foo` is prerequisite of `.PHONY`, then `make` always compile `foo`, even when `foo` exist in your top direcotry.